# ListView refresh items

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with some items, but after I update a Database I'd like to "refresh" the ListView. Anyone can help me?

*EDIT: populateListView add items to ListView*

```
public void populateListView()
{
    String URL = config.getUrl_For_Query() + ",&nameq=Select&tipo=select"; // my URL
    String jsonString = reading.execute_query(URL); // jsonString is formatted well

    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("elenco");
        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) // I scan all array
        {
            JSONObject nameObj = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
            // I retrieve all information  
            allNames.add(nameObj.getString("name")); // Name
            allLng.add(nameObj.getString("lng")); // Another information

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); }

    List<String> Array =  new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<allNames.size();i++) // I add all values
    {
        String value = allNames.get(i).toString() + ", \n\t" + allLng.get(i).toString();
        Array.add(value); // here I populate my Array

    }

    final ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.List);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array));

    //
    // Click
    //

}
```

*saveChanges*

```
public void saveChanges()
{
    // I update a Database
    // And then I'd like to refresh ListView's items
    populateListView(); // Update ListView
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the new items are added below the others

Comment: Well you create a new `Adapter` each time so the problem must be in how you populate the array. Show us the code where you populate it. I am sure we will find the error there.

Comment: Look above, I edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Comparator`. There you define what to compare and how, in the `compare()` method you define what should be returned from two of your instances. Here's an example for a `String` `Comparator`.

```
Comparator myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(final String user1, final String user2) {
    // This would return the ASCII representation of the first character of each string
    return (int) user2.charAt(0) - (int) user1.charAt(0);
  };
};

adapter.sort(myComparator);
```

This way, when you add an item, you don't have to recreate the whole `Adapter` but it will be sorted instead. But don't forget to call `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, this will make (amongs other things) to refresh your layout.

Comment: I don't want old items, but only the new I get with saveChanges(). And where have I to add .notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Once you've made the change to your `Adapter`, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ArrayAdapter.insert method to insert objects in specific index.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T, int)

Answer (score 0):

At first take a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) tutorial about SQlite database in Android. 
So, your problem is that new items are added at the end of the list. Huh? This is because you have not notified `Adapter` from the changes of the Array.
`ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);`
Your first solution is to clear Adapter before updating Database. Sth like:
`Adapter.clear();` can do that. This way your Adapter is empty before updating database and new items are inserted. You can use `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanched();` for awaring Adapter about the changes.
In above tutorial there is a custom Adapter. It uses this code:

`List<String> Array =  new ArrayList<String>();`
`Array = (ArrayList<String>) db.getAllContacts();`
`Adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity() [in fragment case or getApplicationContext() in Activity case], R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Array);`

This way there is no need for clearing Adapter because it automatically does that. Wherever you use this method, updated adapter is used for showing the list.